# How to print current function name when executed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say there is a unbelievable **long and complicated** JavaScript file, is there a way (such as editing Function prototype) to print current function name when this function is executed?
(Using `console.log()` to print function name is not practical in this scenario.)

Comment: You mean you cannot edit the source code? Would setting a debugger breakpoint help?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: What if there is too many functions? It's not practical to do this manually.

Comment: Do you mean you want to print *every* function's name at the moment they're executed? (Without changing the code of any of those functions?) Wouldn't that result in a rather long log?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, but the point is how to print the function name automatically.

Comment: The runtime may have this kind of tracing option. Where are you running that Javascript?